# Powershell: Format-Table | Export-Csv

Tags: powershell

I need to export some data out of Power BI Admin portal.

```
Get-PowerBiWorkspace | Format-Table | Export-Csv "MyFile.csv"
```

Now one would expect to have the data in the csv. But the results of `Get-PowerBiWorkspace | Format-Table` are not in the csv, just one column and a lot of empty columns.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Format-*` commands should never be used for anything you want to pipe to anything else. They should only be used for displaying things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are sending to csv, you don't want to send it through format-table first.  Just go directly from get-powerbiworkspace to output-csv:

```
Get-PowerBiWorkspace | Export-Csv "MyFile.csv"
```

Answer (score 3):

Leave the `Format-Table` out. It's destroying the objects you want to output to the CSV file and converts them into other objects.

```
C:\> Get-Process | Select -First 2

NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
    25    30,54      32,29       0,16    3168   1 ApplicationFrameHost
    9     1,82       6,34       0,00    3832   0 armsvc

C:\> (Get-Process | Select -First 2)[0].GetType().FullName
System.Diagnostics.Process

C:\> Get-Process | Select -First 2 | Format-Table

NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
    25    30,54      32,29       0,16    3168   1 ApplicationFrameHost
    9     1,82       6,34       0,00    3832   0 armsvc

C:\> (Get-Process | Select -First 2 | Format-Table)[0].GetType().FullName
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData

C:\> (Get-Process | Select -First 2 | Format-Table)[0] | Get-Member


TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData

Name                                    MemberType Definition
----                                    ---------- ----------
Equals                                  Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode                             Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType                                 Method     type GetType()
ToString                                Method     string ToString()
autosizeInfo                            Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.AutosizeInfo, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 autosizeInfo {get;set;}
ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd Property   string ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd {get;}
groupingEntry                           Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupingEntry, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 groupingEntry {get;set;}
pageFooterEntry                         Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.PageFooterEntry, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 pageFooterEntry {get;set;}
pageHeaderEntry                         Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.PageHeaderEntry, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 pageHeaderEntry {get;set;}
shapeInfo                               Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ShapeInfo, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 shapeInfo {get;set;}
```

You should be perfectly fine without `Format-Table`.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. It's weird though cause ```Get-PowerBiWorkspace | Format-Table``` shows more of a list. Well it works thanks lots!